# REST Route best practices for creating resources

Tags: rest, api-design

I have some REST API endpoints set up to create a blog post. Each blog Post is owned by a user. I have the following routes:

```
/users [GET, POST]: Get a list of all users, POST to this endpoint to create a new user
/users/<id> [GET]: Get info for the specified user
/users/<id>/posts [GET]: Get all posts for the specified user
```

Now the question I have is, when creating a new Post, do I post to this endpoint and provide a `{'user_id': <user_id>}` in the `POST` payload:

`/posts`

Or use this endpoint which would not require the `user_id` in the payload:

`/users/<id>/posts`

My instinct tells me it should `POST` to `/posts` and provide the `user_id` as part of the payload but if I'm making a post for a specific user, it should use the latter case. \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of creating a new post, the user_id is just another attribute, like the title or body text. The fact that `GET /users/:id/posts` returns a list of posts for that user is irrelevant when creating a new post. Remember that REST endpoints are a conceptual representation of something, not actual files on a disk.

If `GET /users/:id/posts` returns a collection of objects, I would be surprised to find a POST endpoint to the same path when creating a new post. I typically feel a PUT to a collection is more appropriate, which then modifies the collection rather than creating a whole new resource.

Instead, think about the GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE verbs being a cohesive set of actions on a resource. I would expect:

- `POST /posts` to create a new post.
- `PUT /posts/:id` to update a post.
- `GET /posts/:id` to return a single post.
- `DELETE /posts/:id` to delete a single post.
- `GET /posts` to return a collection of posts.

  - `GET /posts?user_id=NNN` can just as easily return posts for a single user as `GET /users/:id/posts`. That is a matter of documentation for your API.

Answer (score 0):

```
/users/<id>/posts [GET]: Get all posts for the specified user
```

The first thing that I notice is that we would expect the representation of this resource to change when a new post is added.  Therefore, I would normally want the HTTP request that causes this resource to change to reference the same target URI, so that we can take advantage of [general-purpose cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons).

Therefore, I would argue for

```
POST /users/<id>/posts
```

The key idea here being that the URI we use is the same - the actual spelling of the URI doesn't matter very much.  The same principle would hold for

```
GET /ff1fe3f4-de8e-4fbc-b7e9-c43f5a9a6859
POST /ff1fe3f4-de8e-4fbc-b7e9-c43f5a9a6859
```

If [caching isn't important to you](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-storing-responses-in-caches), then you can reasonably design your interface so that read and write use different resource identifiers.  I'd expect a PR that makes another choice to include a decision record (see [Nygard 2011](https://cognitect.com/blog/2011/11/15/documenting-architecture-decisions), or [Kruchten 2009](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rafael-Capilla-2/publication/220093619_The_Decision_View%27s_Role_in_Software_Architecture_Practice/links/0912f50890a588c20e000000/The-Decision-Views-Role-in-Software-Architecture-Practice.pdf?origin=publication_detail)) describing the analysis done to understand the tradeoff balance.

---

Looking at Laiv's answer, I'm reminded that I should probably be more clear about the mechanism I'm suggesting.

Assuming that the server wants to announce the creation of a new resource, and that the server is going to choose the identifier of the new resource, the interaction would look like:

```
POST /users/<id>/posts 

...
```

```
201 Created
Location: /somewhere-chosen-by-the-server
```

General purpose HTTP components aren't going to care what spelling conventions are used in the URI of the new resource.  So `/users/123/posts/6789` would be fine, as would `/posts/6789` or `/91ca7e41-8298-450d-8d8f-9327f8d64867`.  It's an opaque identifier.

(Which isn't to say that it doesn't matter - *humans* will want identifiers that are sensible, in much the same way that we want variable names to be sensible.)

---

If all you are really doing is modifying a single resource (ie: posts aren't represented by individual resources, but instead are data embedded within the /user//posts resource), then we certainly want to be using /user//posts as the target URI, because (again) that's the important document we are changing, and general purpose caches will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above.

Assuming posts are created by the blog's owner and owners MUST be authenticated and authorized.<sup>1</sup>

```html
POST /posts 
Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

No `user_id`. Neither in the path nor the payload.

The user's `ID` is implicit. It's known by the server because the authorization is attached to the request (stateless server) or it's already in the session (stateful server).

Them you can allow bloggers to search their blog posts

```
<!-- mines -->
GET /posts
Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Again, the `user_id` is already implicit. It's not like I will search/list someone else's post. So why do I need `/users/{id}/post`?

By the same reasoning, authenticated user's data could be accessible at

```
GET /me
Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Once more, no `id` whatsoever.

A reason to support `user_id` in previous routes could be if we had a back office or a browser to navigate through bloggers. But that would be a good reason to make another API. Managing blogs and posts with the browser's API is possible and we could argue that it's convenient but, IMO, it's a bad decision. Command-query responsibility segregation (as a design strategy) exists for a reason.

Finally, it has been already commented but I will stress it a big more.

**It's not mandatory that the resource sent by POST is (1:1) the same resource retrieved by GET**. Otherwise, we couldn't create resources with data unknown by the client.

---

<sup>`/blog/{bid}/posts` if owners manage different blogs from the same account or|and session</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
/GetUserPostsById?id={id}
/AddPosts
[{
  id:
  userid: 
  content:
}]
```

The problem with parameters in the path, especially with nested objects is that it becomes hard to disambiguate the endpoint.

for example consider:

```
/GetPostsByUserIdAndCategoryId?id=ewan&category=hottake
/users/ewan/posts/hottake

/GetUsersWithIdStartingWithAndPostsInCategoryId?idStartsWith=e&category=hottake
/users/e/posts/hottake
```

You are identifying parameters by ordinal and mixing in route identifiers in the same path string. Its a hot mess